# Duplicate project in xcode workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I was working in my xcode workspace. I downloaded a pod and the xcode gave me following warning:

[image]

I allowed that to happen and after that, I am getting a duplicate of my own project in workspace.

[image]

How to remove the duplicate project?

Answer (score 1):

First take backup your project then right click on duplicate copy and delete.